# How to control specific turtles movement

Tags: netlogo

I'm working on a new project in Logo.

I am trying to make a a specific turtle with a different shape to stay still at the same position throughout the running; I tried to use `[set xcor and ycor]`, but it didn't work.

How can I do it?

```
breed [cars car]
breed [gas_stations gas_station]


turtles-own [
   speed
   movement
   time-of-waiting
   extra-load
]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ setup-road ]
  setup-cars
  create-gas_stations 1 [
    set shape "gas"
    set size 5
    set color blue
    set xcor 25 set ycor 5
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-road ;; patch procedure
  ifelse pycor < 4 and pycor > -4 [set pcolor black ]
  [set pcolor green ]
   if pycor < 3 and pycor > -3 [ set pcolor gray ]
  if pycor > -3 and pycor < 3 and pxcor > 23 and pxcor < 27
   [set pcolor yellow ]

end
```

Comment: The code you have shown us doesn't move ANY turtle. But you probably want to set movement to 0 for gas-stations. You probably also want the code that actually moves turtles to `ask cars` rather than `ask turtles`. If you want a sensible answer, please show us the code that doesn't work.

Comment: hello everyone, i want to make a number of turtles cars to move in a row after each other with a space between them , and that's what i got but it doesn't work right
this is the code that i tried :
   

     to go
        ask cars [
         set xcor xcor + 3 
         tick
        end